# Systemd Bootloader not shown (Dualboot Windows10 / Pop!_OS)

Tags: systemd, windows, dual-boot, pop-os

I've recently replaced my dualboot (Ubuntu/Win10) by (Pop!_OS 20.04/Win10).
Now, when I start my computer, no boot menu is shown and it boots directly into windows.
Here's what I've tried so far:

- I repaired the systemd-bootloader as described [here](https://support.system76.com/articles/bootloader/), however, this didn't fix my problem.
- I Inserted an Ubuntu Livestick (which has GRUB installed) to get into the grub menu. From there I **don't** start ubuntu, but go into the GRUB command line and set the bootloader to systemd as follows:

  - `chainloader (hd2,1)/efi/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi`
  - `boot`

  This lets me boot into Pop!_OS (But doesn't show a menu as well, so I could not boot into windows from there). It also shows, that the systemd bootloader is generally working
- I then figured that the problem might be with windows, so I booted into windows and then checked the Boot Configuration Data with `bcdedit`. I had a similar issue with my ubuntu installation and I could fix it by defining the path of the grub efi file as
  `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`. Turns out, there really is an issue there.

  - First of all, there is the bottom line telling me "*A device which does not exist was specified*".
  - Second, it seems like the wrong device is chosen for the `{bootmgr}`. Currently, the device is defined as "partition=C:". However, the EFI files I'm looking for are not on the C: partition but on Disk1Partition1. The problem is, I don't know what this partition is called, i.e. how I need to define it in the bcdedit entry such that it gets recognized during startup.
    Here's the output of `bcdedit`

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>bcdedit
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\systemd\systemd-bootx64.efi                                                                                                    
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {c9199aab-b651-11ea-8b88-3ce1a1c4ba83}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30
Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {c9199aae-b651-11ea-8b88-3ce1a1c4ba83}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {c9199aab-b651-11ea-8b88-3ce1a1c4ba83}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto
A device which does not exist was specified.
```

And here is the Disk Management window of Windows, which shows you my configuration. the systemd-efi files are located on Disk1 Partition1.

[image: Disk Management Windows]

Also, here's some information about my computer

[image: Information Computer]

Does anyone have a clue on how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which computer model are you using? The implementation of Uefi differs from brand to brand...

Comment: You can mount Disk1Part1 with `diskpart`. Do it similar to [this guide](https://manjaro.site/how-to-mount-macos-efi-partition-from-windows-10/). Perhaps you can thengive windows the correct partition...

Comment: i mounted the EFI partition and assigned its letter to the bcdedit-entry. However, it changed nothing. After the reboot directly booted into windows, the entry in bcdedit was overwritten as "partition=\Device\Harddiskvolume2".

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search enginre results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue with the help of the comments. Thank you all! For completeness, I quickly state all the steps I took to fix this:

**Quickfix - If you quickly need to boot without solving the actual problem**

- Insert a livestick with a functioning bootloader (I used Ubuntu 20.04 with GRUB)
- Once the GRUB from the livestick started, interrupt the bootloading process by pressing *c* or *esc*.
- Now, define the bootloader, that you want to use (for me, it was the systemd bootloader, located on my harddisk2, partition 1)

  `chainloader (hd2,1)/efi/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi`

  `boot`

This should let you boot with the defined bootloader.

**Fix the problem**

- I first repaired the systemd bootloader according to [this](https://support.system76.com/articles/bootloader/) tutorial. (You might need to use the quickfix above to boot into your linux system)
- As this didn't solve the issue, I booted into windows, executed (as administrator) the command prompt.
- I mounted my EFI partition, by following [this guide](https://manjaro.site/how-to-mount-macos-efi-partition-from-windows-10/) (I mounted it at V:).
- Then, I added the EFI file as {bootmgr} path and the mounted EFI partition as a device in my bcdedit {bootmgr} entry

  `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\systemd\systemd-bootx64.efi`

  `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} device partition=V:`
- I then rebooted (it again booted directly into windows) and saw, that the bcdedit device entry of {bootmgr} changed from *partition=V:* to *partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2*
- I rebooted again, and it worked. So maybe I could have directly set the device to *partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2*... However, this worked for me.